# Tab shortcode plugin renders incorrectly

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, tabs

I've used the [tabs shortcode plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tabs-shortcode/) before, but it's never done this before.

Where it normally renders tabs much like the built in tabs that come with Wordpress, this time its just rendering a bulleted list.

Here's my code:

```
[tabs]
[tab title="Financials"]
<ul>
        <li>Bookkeeping to balance</li>
        <li>Audit preparations</li>
        <li>Cipro company registration</li>
        <li>SARS eFiling</li>
        <li>UIF</li>
</ul>
[/tab]
[tab title="Office Administration"]
<ul>
        <li>Development of useful templates in Microsoft Office programs
<ul>
        <li>Excel formulas</li>
        <li>Letterheads</li>
        <li>Form letters</li>
</ul>
</li>
        <li>Mail mergers</li>
        <li>Database cleanups</li>
        <li>Data capture</li>
        <li>Desktop publishing</li>
</ul>
[/tab]
[tab title="Miscellaneous"]
<ul>
        <li>Blogging and blog management</li>
        <li>Social media updates</li>
        <li>Web content management</li>
</ul>
[/tab]
[/tabs]
```

One guy on IRC said that there's missing html elements, css and jquery tabs isn't loaded:

> [17:06] [Kenshino_] For one you're missing html elements
>   [17:06] [Kenshino_] You also likely lack the css
>   [17:07] [Kenshino_] jQuery tabs isn't even loaded

I'm not sure what to do about this because I've never had this issue before. Can anyone suggest steps I can take to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you didn't complete format...
Add `[/tabs]` at the end of content...

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in my copy/paste

Comment: Have you tried deactivating-activating plugin ????

Comment: What's actually wrong with this?  It seems to work fine to me.  I go to your site and get three tabs - the three that you've set up.  Inside each tab, a bullet list is displayed.  Isn't that what you're after?

Comment: I decided I'd build the tabs with the in-built tab shortcodes... They just confuse me a little so that's why I prefer the plugin, but the plugin doesn't work on that page